# Font Smoothing Problems with Google Fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

I've been experiencing a strange phenomenon with the webfonts I use on my website. There seems to be **a problem with the font-smoothing properties**. Here you have an example:

[image: bad font smoothing]
[image: good font smoothing]

The first example is how my posts usually display on my 1920x1080 desktop monitor. The second example is *how they should actually display*, achieved through opening the Chrome DevTools and closing them immediately, (*why* does that work, I have no idea).

I've tried a diverse range of methods from the Internet(s), but none seem to work. No *-webkit-font-smoothing*, no *text-shadow*, nothing.

Aditionally, the website seems to *only* have trouble with that display: widescreen 1920x1080. I have tested it in a diversity of displays with diverse amounts of success, but I haven't been able to isolate the cause.

EDIT - MORE INFO:

**Smoothing works just fine** on my Mac Pro 13' with Retina and my iPhone 5, as well as my Android tablet.
**Smoothing doesn't work** in any browser used on my Windows Laptop at 1920x1080.

Again, the problem seems to appear at widescreen displays only.

Comment: Are you trying with different browsers? Chrome, as opposite than people thinks, have a lot of problems with the font antialiasing. If you mix chrome with windows (that's the poor antialiasing of all current operating systems called TrueType) will produce a very poor quality font rendering. Try with IE or Firefox to isolate the problem.

Comment: Just added some info :)

Comment: Windows have the poor font antialiasing of the world. It's called TrueType. It's horrible, and you can't change it in a webpage. I'm sure if you try to test in a Linux you'll seen the same that you can see in your Mac. Both of them have good antialiasing